# Create Python shell script with command line arguments

Tags: python, shell, scripting, argparse

So I created a couple of modules: module1.py and module2.py and they're both working fine.

But now I would like to call them from the command line using a script by specifying a corresponding option. For example:

```
python launchscript.py -l somefile.txt
```

Or

```
python launchscript.py -x
```

First option should sent the parameter and execute main() from module1.py and second option should execute main() from module2.py

This launch script should be extensible as I add more internal modules and it should offer built-in command line help.

I'm a python beginner, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have tagged this `argparse` - have you tried actually using that library? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Correct. I tried to use argparse but to no avail, I'm still lost, so I decided to specify the whole requirement. So taking that into account my question would be how to implement a command line shell from Python?

Comment: Then your question is too broad for SO - this isn't a code-writing or tutorial service. However, if you provided a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempted code and a precise problem description (error traceback, inputs and expected and actual outputs, etc.) that would be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm responding to myself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Created on Nov 19, 2014


@author: yllanos
'''
# Standard libraries
import sys
import argparse

# External libraries

# Product modules
import module1 as dbs
import module2 as gen

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', action='store', dest='file',
                help='Does something with a file')
    parser.add_argument('-x', '--xml', action='store_true', dest='xml_switch',
                help='Does some other thing')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='0.1')
    ar = parser.parse_args()

    if ar.file:
        dbs.main(argv[1])
    else:
        None

    if ar.xml_switch:
        gen.main()
    else:
        None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) == 0:
        print "Usage: ebiller command [OPTION]"
        exit
    else:
        main(sys.argv[1:])
```